# How do I conditionally add a new line and tabs in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of values `id, name, category, description` and a variable amount of `keyword` values; between 0 and 18 for each row. I want to create a list of those values in the form of:

```
(id, 'keyword')
, (id, 'keyword')
```

Where the list only increments if there is a keyword to go with the identifier. This is meant to be an easy manual list for a SQL `INSERT` statement.

I realize that I can use `&CHAR(9)` for inserting tabs and `&CHAR(10)` for inserting new lines, and thus my sequence for proper tabulation is `&CHAR(10)&CHAR(9)&CHAR(9)` for each new entry.

```
=IF(G2<>"",CONCATENATE("(",A2,", '",UPPER(G2),"')"),"")
&CHAR(10)&CHAR(9)&CHAR(9)&
IF(H2<>"",CONCATENATE("(",A2,", '",UPPER(H2),"')"),"")
```

I've tried several different combinations such as:

```
=IF(G2<>"",CONCATENATE("(",A2,", '",UPPER(G2),"')"),"")+
IF(H2<>"",CHAR(10)&CHAR(9)&CHAR(9)&CONCATENATE("(",A2,", '",UPPER(H2),"')"),"")
```

and

```
=IF(G2<>"",CONCATENATE("(",A2,", '",UPPER(G2),"')",CHAR(10),CHAR(9),CHAR(9)),"")+
IF(H2<>"",CONCATENATE("(",A2,", '",UPPER(H2),"')"),"")
```

and

```
=IF(G2<>"",CONCATENATE("(",A2,", '",UPPER(G2),"')"),"")+
IF(H2<>"",CONCATENATE(CHAR(10),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),"(",A2,", '",UPPER(H2),"')"),"")
```

which all give errors in calculation. Has anyone else been dying to know how to do this and had this kind of frustration? Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out within an hour of posting, but neglected to post the solution here in case anyone else wanted to know.

You have to `CONCATENATE` the whole series of `IF` blocks and add the `CHAR(10)` and `CHAR(9)`s to the inner `CONCATENATE` blocks, like so:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(G2<>"",CONCATENATE("(",A2,", '",UPPER(G2),"')"),""),
IF(H2<>"",CONCATENATE(CHAR(10),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),"(",A2,", '",UPPER(H2),"')"),""))
```

Thanks,

-C§